# Why is my SQL table result in two lines? check the screenshot below

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

After creating and inserting values into my table, when I look out for the results, I get it in two lines. I don't know what to do. please help.[SQL search result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzzBX.png)

Comment: Why is a MySQL question tagged as `oracle` (which is for the Oracle database product, not for everything Oracle owns), and especially tagged specifically as `oracle11g` (a specific version of Oracle database)? I will remove all tags except MySQL; feel free to add them back, but you better have a good reason for doing so, or else I or someone else will remove them again.

Comment: OK - looking at your attached image, it seems that you are not using MySQL but rather Oracle database. Right? Then - the question is really about SQL\*Plus, not the database itself. You must have declared `EMPLOEE_NAME` as a very long string. In SQL\*Plus, issue the command `column employee_name format a16` (for example - if the names will be at most 16 characters) and try again. SQL\*Plus doesn't know how long the names will be - it reserves enough room for the declared length, which makes the name by itself take a full line of text.

Comment: What is the schema of `employee_database` table?

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate what you were already told in a comment.

This is (more or less) what you have:

```
SQL> create table employee_database
  2    (employee_name  varchar2(50),
  3     street         varchar2(30),
  4     city           varchar2(30));

Table created.

SQL> insert into employee_database values ('abc', 'bgefdc street', 'chennai');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from employee_database;

EMPLOYEE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------
STREET                         CITY
------------------------------ ------------------------------
abc
bgefdc street                  chennai
```

If you format columns (basically, *shorten* columns as they are too long for the current line size):

```
SQL> col employee_name format a20
SQL> col street        format a20
SQL> col city          format a20
SQL>
SQL> select * from employee_database;

EMPLOYEE_NAME        STREET               CITY
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
abc                  bgefdc street        chennai

SQL>
```

---

Alternatively, enlarge line size (I'll first revert columns' formatting):

```
SQL> col employee_name format a50
SQL> col street        format a30
SQL> col city          format a30
SQL> select * from employee_database;

EMPLOYEE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------
STREET                         CITY
------------------------------ ------------------------------
abc
bgefdc street                  chennai


SQL> set linesize 200
SQL> select * from employee_database;

EMPLOYEE_NAME                                      STREET                         CITY
-------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------
abc                                                bgefdc street                  chennai

SQL>
```